# Change Credential Retrieval in SSRS with powershell

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I want to change SSRS data source credential retrieval from using the following credentials to without any credentials with powershell and script fails.

I want to change value 'Store' to 'None' according to this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportservice2010.credentialretrievalenum?view=sqlserver-2016#ReportService2010_CredentialRetrievalEnum_None

This is my code:

```
$uri ='http://ServerName/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl'

$reporting = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential -namespace "ReportingWebService"
$DataSources = $reporting.ListChildren('/', $true) | Where-Object  {$_.Name -eq "DataSourceName"}   

  foreach($Object in $DataSources) {
   $dataSource =$reporting.GetDataSourceContents($Object.path)
   #$dataSource.CredentialRetrieval="None"
  $dataSource.CredentialRetrieval=[ReportingWebService.CredentialRetrievalEnum]::None
   $reporting.SetDataSourceContents($Object.path,$dataSource)
 }
```

This is the error:

> Exception calling "SetDataSourceContents" with "2" argument(s): "The combination of values for the fields UserName and CredentialRetrieval are not valid. ---> 
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidElementCombinationException: The combination of values for the fields UserName and CredentialRetrieval are not valid."
>   At line:13 char:4
>   +    $reporting.SetDataSourceContents($Object.path,$dataSource)
>   +    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SoapException

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i actually did not change existent credential retrieval settings 'Store' with required Username parameter.
To resolve it i should create new data source definition with new credential retrieval settings and apply it to my data source:

```
$uri ='http://servername/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl'
$reporting = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential
$type=$reporting.GetType().Namespace
$DataSources = $reporting.ListChildren('/', $true) | Where-Object  {$_.Name -eq "Data source name"} 

 foreach($Object in $DataSources) {
   $dataSource =$reporting.GetDataSourceContents($Object.path)
    $dataSourceDefinitionType = ($type + '.DataSourceDefinition');
    $dataSourceDefinition = New-Object ($dataSourceDefinitionType);
    $dataSourceDefinition.Extension = $dataSource.Extension; #get data from existent data source definition
    $dataSourceDefinition.ConnectString = $dataSource.ConnectString #get data from existent data source definition
    $credentialRetrievalDataType = ($type + '.CredentialRetrievalEnum'); 
    $credentialRetrieval = new-object ($credentialRetrievalDataType);
    $credentialRetrieval.value__ = 3;
    $dataSourceDefinition.CredentialRetrieval = $credentialRetrieval;
    $dataSourceDefinition.WindowsCredentials = $dataSource.WindowsCredentials; #get data from existent data source definition
    $dataSourceDefinition.Enabled = $dataSource.Enabled; #get data from existent data source definition
    $dataSourceDefinition.EnabledSpecified = $dataSource.EnabledSpecified; #get data from existent data source definition
    $reporting.SetDataSourceContents($Object.path,$dataSourceDefinition)
  }
```